# Convert 6 volts dc to 300 volts dc

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, radiation

I am trying to build a portable Geiger-Müller tube that is run on 4x AA batteries. However, the tube runs on 300 volts. What is the most efficient way to do this? I have looked for a transformer that I could drive with a 555 timer, but I couldn't find any transformers meeting my specifications.

Comment: I find tons of circuits and suggestions when googling for 555 high voltage or similar stuff, what is wrong with all those circuits, what is one of your requirements that makes them all not match?

Comment: You need to specify the current or power requirements as well as it is quite relevant to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Convert 6 volts dc to 300 volts dc. What is the most efficient way to do this.

1 minute on google found this: -

[image]

This will be about 70% efficient and probably a bit more efficient than using a 555. Read the data sheet on the LT3573 for detail on what transformer they recommend.

Then there is this beast: -

[image]

I used the term "5V to 300V converter" to search for images and note that I changed 6V to 5V because it is more likely to lead to a better search result. You'll also need to be able to generate 300V as the batteries droop a bit too.

Comment: IIRC 5 mA is *waaay* overkill for a GM tube, the typical series resistor is 3 .. 10 MOhm.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen my point is that choosing the right google terminology pays dividends.

Answer (score 3):

A GM tube consumes very little current, so the best contribution to efficiency is to sense the high voltage and turn off the HV generator when it is high enough, and do so without conmsuming a 'large' current for the feedback. The second circuit Andy shows is a good HV genarator, but it has a 3M5 feedback/sense resistor, which is high enough for other purposes, but a bit on the low (!) side for a GM circuit. This circuit for instance has a 20M feedback:

[image]

It uses a 6V/220V transformer and a Jacobs-ladder multiplier. (But I think there is something wrong with this circuit: the HV generator lacks a ground connection.)

Googling Geiger counter circuit" or something similar will give you lots of suggestions, but be aware that they might be for tubes that work on a different voltage and/or current.

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on what you're wanting the GM tube to do. If you're anticipating making a device that will tell you how many minutes or hours before you receive a fatal dose of radiation your power supply will need to handle a lot more current. If you just looking for small increases above background, then a very small current capability is required.

Comment: A typical GM circuit has a 10M resistor between te HV source and the GM tube, so even if the GM tube is a permanent short the current drawn from a 300V HV would be only 30 uA.

Comment: I see some circuits using the SI3BG with about 5x higher current. Not sure what you need to do in order to be able to read at the full rate (70kHz or something like that for 300R/h).

Comment: yes, ground is missing, add a connection from ground to the  transformer end of C5

Comment: there's other "unusual features" in that circuit too, R2 seems unusually high for a start.

Comment: Can I ask you what program that was drawn in? I love this 'Elektuur' style but this is the first time I've ever seen a screen capture instead of a photo of that schematic style.